Existence of symmetric total measures
Is it consistent that there is a total finitely additive measure $μ$ on $ℝ$ extending the Lebesgue measure such that for every Borel Lebesgue-measure-preserving bijection $f$ of $ℝ$, $∀α∈Ord \, ∀s∈Ord^ω \; (V_α,∈,s, μ) ≡ (V_α,∈,s, f_*(μ))$ ?
$f_*(μ)(f[X]) = μ(X)$, i.e. $f_*(μ)$ is the pushforward measure.  '$≡$' means elementarily equivalent, i.e. having the same theory.
The use of $ℝ$ rather than $ℝ^n$ does not affect the question since we have measure-preserving bijections.  The motivation for the requirement on theories is that for $ℝ^3$, we cannot have rotation invariance (Banach-Tarski paradox), so we instead only require that the original and the rotated measure are indistinguishable, even by queries using reals or other countable sequences of ordinals as parameters — and we extend this requirement to all Borel Lebesgue-measure-preserving bijections instead of just rotations.
I expect that the answer is yes by using a Solovay model $\operatorname{Col}(ω, <\text{inaccessible})$ to get all $\operatorname{OD}(Ord^ω)$ sets of reals measurable, and then somehow generically extending the measure, but I do not know how to set up and prove the invariances.
The elementary equivalence requirement prevents translation invariance because each of the $f_*(μ)$ would also be translation invariant, and a translation of an interval can be transformed into a rotation of a region on $ℝ^n$ encoded into $ℝ$.  Without the elementary equivalence requirement, we can have translation invariance even in $ℝ^n$, or other invariances as long their group is amenable (in discrete topology); not sure if translation invariance can be supplemented with, for each of the $n$ axes, scale equivariance.
Extensions
Under CH (the Continuum Hypothesis), $μ$ cannot be countably additive, but without CH, one can also ask this question about countably additive $μ$.
A natural extension is to weaken "Lebesgue-measure-preserving" to $∃α>0 \, ∃b \, ∀(\text{Borel } X) \, a μ(X) ≤ μ(f[X]) ≤ b μ(X)$ and use rescaled $f_*(μ)$.  Rescaling works if for every $ε>0$, there is a finite Borel partition $(S_1,S_2,...)$ of $ℝ$ such that $∀i \, ∃c \, ∀(\text{Borel } X⊆S_i) \, c μ(X) ≤ μ(f[X]) ≤ (c+ε) μ(X)$.
Conceptual side note
The conceptual tension between measures/probabilities and the axiom of choice can be resolved by:
(a) considering some sets nonmeasurable and denying (i) metaphysical possibility of picking a random real number in [0,1], or (ii) metaphysical existence of arbitrary sets of reals, or (iii) everything having a probability,
(b) denying the axiom of choice, or 
(c) relaxing some of the rules of measure/probability (such as by allowing the outcome of "independent" experiments to depend on the order in which they are performed) and seeing how much is still possible with total measures.
While the default resolution is (a), I think (c) also leads to interesting mathematical questions, such as the above.
